# Passing Objects Inside A CustomControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, itemscontrol

I am working on a custom control and I was wondering what would be the best way to pass some custom properties from my `ItemsControl` to my `ItemsContainer`s. The properties are few custom values which `ItemsContainer` should be able to use then.

Anybody had the same issue while creating custom controls? Whats the most common way to solve this in code?

I think using DataTriggers or binding to RelativeSource's from ItemsContainer's ControlTemplate is not the very best way.

Is there an object-orientend way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `DataTrigger`s or relative bindings, you can create your own `ItemsControl` and `ItemsControl` containers (by inheriting `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem` for example) and then instantiate the containers with specific properties by overriding the [ItemsControl.GetContainerForItemOverride Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx) and finally bind your custom control properties to the properties defined on your Container.

That being said, there is nothing wrong using `DataTriggers` and managing these properties on your ViewModels.

Comment: I thought DataTriggers last performance since each item has to go find ancestor. That's why I am currently looking for an object-oriented method. Do DataTriggers impact drawing performance in a bad way? Do you have an example of GetContainerForItemOverride that passes dependencyobjects to ItemsContainers?

Comment: DataTriggers use `Binding` so they can be bad from a memory and performance point of view if used extensively. `GetContainerForItemOverride` basically just return a new container. For example in the ListBox case, it will just perform : return new ListBoxItem(); In your case, you could do something like return new MyListBoxItem() { MyCustomProperty = some_value }; you also can use the `ItemsControl.PrepareContainerForItemOverride` Method to customize your container.

Comment: Have you had a case where you used RelativeSource inside each TreeViewItem to go find and bind to a property from the TreeView? Lets say you have 3 levels of depth, without virtualization, each level contains about 500 items. What should i do in such case?

Comment: I think that the cost of a single relative binding will be negligeable before the cost of creating and managing all of the visuals in a case like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) is what you need. Define few in your uses control and set them in xaml with bindings for example.

Comment: I am using DependencyProperties, of course, but i am looking for a fast way to use dp's from my ItemsControl in my ItemsContainers. :)

Comment: Yes, I completely misread the question. Apologies. I've used RelativeSource in the case described by you. I see nothing wrong in using it to bind to some common for the usercontrol values.

Comment: Have you had a case where you used RelativeSource inside each TreeViewItem to bind to a property from the TreeView? Lets say you have 3 levels of depth, without virtualization, each level contains about 500 items.

Comment: No, not really. I think you should consider extending your question with this information.